# EJS Helper function moongose

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

recently I faced the problem that the result from database is not as not be able to display on the page. What am I doing wrong ?

**This is the function code which is located in index.js**

```
res.locals.get_user_name = function () {
    User.findOne({_id: 2}).exec().then(function (user) {
        return user.name;
    });
};
```

**And this is a code template EJS**

`<div class="name"><% get_user_name() %></div>`

Comment: do you see any errors?

Comment: There are no errors. I tried to simply return the unit and everything worked.

Comment: get_user_name is not returning anything. Also you are using async code with sync code. I suggest you get familiar with promises and async code.

Comment: I tried to output the result to the console, everything worked. But in the template the result is not displayed

Comment: I was trying to use Bluebird but this also yielded no results